# Is this an effective technique to propagate climbers with aerial roots

Tags: propagation, vines, monstera, climbers, aroid

I bought a Monstera "Monkey mask" in a small pot. Right now, it is erect because the stem is still short. The stem is already showing button-sized aerial roots popping-out of the main stem.

I have found ways to propagate by stem cuttings on Youtube, but this method means that you must wait until a segment gives-out its own roots *after* it was cut. Success rate is not 100% given the risk of damping-off, and for small plants the risk may be too high.

My question is whether this method is better and faster:

- I plant the vine at the edge of a long pot,
- I let the vine grow without support, allowing it to trail on the surface of the potting soil
- The vine will develop aerial roots along the stem. The roots will grow into the potting soil,
- I cut the stem into segments. Each segment contains at-least one leaf and one set of fully-developed roots at its base.
- As a response to cutting, each segment will set a new branch,
- When big enough, the individual plants can be planted into their own pot.

Is that method faster and better than the conventional methods?